# How to auto focus a field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js

I'm writing a small chat client/server app with KnockoutJS and Node.js, everything is good, except for the fact, that after I send a message, I lose focus on the message field, and users have to reclick it everytime they want to type (very annoying). Do you guys know what I can do? Here is the template:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="chatRoom">
<div id="chatContainer" class="chatContainer">
    <div class="chatFrom">
        <i id="chatClose" class="chatSprite chatClose" data-bind='click: function() { server.removeChat(this) }'></i>
    </div>
    <div class="chatMessages">
        <ul id="chatHolder">
        {{each messages()}}
            <li><div class="chatFromText">From: ${ from }</div>
            <div class="chatTime">${ time }</div><div class="chatMsg">${ text }</div></li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="chatControls">
    <form data-bind="submit: function() { send($('#'+channel).val()); $('#'+channel).focus(); }">
        <input type="text" id="${ channel }" name="message" class="chatText" style="color: #999;" value="Message Here" data-bind='click: function() {
            $("#"+channel).val("").css("color", "#000");
        }'  />
        <i class="chatSprite chatSend" data-bind="click: function() { $('.chatSend').parent().submit() }"></i>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

As you can see I have tried every possible way of focusing the field, but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that your issue is likely that your "send" method does an asynchronous post back to the server, in the success callback it probably pushes the message to your messages observableArray.  When this happens your template is re-rendered and your focus is lost.  So, this happens after your `$('#'+channel).focus()` call, because the send completes asynchronously.

Can't be sure without seeing your send function.

One option would be to pass "channel" as another parameter to your "send" function, then in the success callback for your AJAX request after pushing the message to your messages observableArray set the focus based on channel.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/h2A6p/

Comment: RP, you my friend are a master! You were right about the timing between the async call and the re-rendering of the template, so i just put it in the right place and it worked! thank you again

Comment: Hey RP, I think the link to the knockout-latest-debug.js file is broken. So the jsfiddle example is also broken. I've witnissed the same issue before. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of old fiddles were linked to the build output on Github, which no longer exists for KO.  I updated the fiddle.  Let me know if you see any others.

Answer (score 9):

Knockout now has a [hasfocus](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) binding.

Answer (score 2):

Combining Aran's and Arun's answers, the easiest way that works for me is:

```
<input id="channel" type="text" data-bind="hasfocus: true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your send function being asynchronous,

Either set `async = false`, if you are using `ajax`

Alternately, 
you can use a view model property to hold a `boolean` value  and use the `hasfocus` binding

```
function chatVM()
{
    this.focus = ko.observable(true);
}
var vm = new chatVM();
```

And then inside your submit function

```
set vm.focus(true);
```

OR

set `hasfocus` of your message box to true always.

```
div class="msgbox" data-bind="hasfocus: ko.observable(true)"></div>
```